# Using 2 radio button groups with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get 2 radio button groups with twitter bootstrap. But I am able to select only one value out of the four buttons I have. They act as a single radio button group instead of 2 separate groups. I have added a different name field, still **they behave as a single group**. What am I missing out?

```
   <label>Question 1?</label>
   <div id="build-type"  class="btn-group radio-space" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
          <button type="button" id="build-maven"  name="build-type" class="btn btn-default btn-group-justified">maven</button>
          <button type="button" id="build-ant" name="build-type" class="btn btn-default btn-group-justified">ant</button>
   </div>
   <label>Questions 2?</label>
   <div id="test-framework" class="btn-group radio-space" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
          <button type="button" id="test-yes" name="test-framework" class="btn btn-default btn-group-justified">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" id="test-no" name="test-framework" class="btn btn-default btn-group-justified">No</button>
   </div>
```

**Custom CSS**

```
.radio-space{
        width: 60%;
 }
```

Comment: Looks like it's working to me. Have you made sure that the CSS and JS are both included? http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/kc5omwk4/

Comment: @austinthedeveloper Thanks for indicating. I missed out the button.js. But, now it works like a checkbox and not like a radio. Same happens in the jsfiddle link that you gave me as well.